# Problema con certificado SSL en net core 6

Tags: ssl, certificado

Tengo el problema que al levantar mi aplicacion mvc en net core 6 me muestra el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualice mi certificado tanto como en personal y en entidad de certificacion raiz de confianza y expira en 2023

pero me sigue apareciendo que el certificado esta vencido

de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

---

adjunto imagen de la configuracion de certificados del navegador y si se encuentra el certificado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: asumiendo que el certificado fue hecho por ti para localhost, además de agregarlo a los certificados del sistema operativo también deben estar en los certificados del navegador, siempre puedes darle a "Configuración avanzada" y aceptar el certificado ahí que te da 1 semana creo, pero también puedes hacerlo desde las configuraciones del navegador y agregar el certificado en la sección de certificados

Comment: si genera el certificado con el siguiente comando dotnet dev-certs https --trust, ya revise la configuración del navegador y se encuentran el certificado,